# How to pause a scheduled selector?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Is There is any way to pause a particular selector, like :

```
[self schedule:@selector(funcA:) interval:0.05];
```

is it possible to pause this scheduler and then resume.

Another question: is there  any way to check whether a scheduler is running???

Answer (score 4):

**You can pause all of the schedulers using:**

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] pause]
```

**or:**

```
[self pauseSchedulerAndActions];
```

Comment: That will not work,because i need to pause a single scheduler, not all the scheduler.

Comment: Then stop the schedule and when you need schedule again

Comment: You can stop a schedule by(inside the schedule function)

[self unschedule:_cmd]

Comment: That will unschedule the entire event, not pause it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
[self unschedule:@selector(funA:)];
```

Comment: It will unschedule the selector, not pause it.

Answer (score 3):

Possibly you can make a `bool` variable in your class that will identify if your object is scheduled or not. And in your `funcA` check the variable value. This solution will be more efficient then unscheduling and scheduling again.

Answer (score 1):

Add the scheduler to a dummy CCNode:

[dummyNode schedule:@selector(funcA:) interval:0.05];

Then you can use:

[dummyNode pauseSchedulerAndActions];

It will only pause schedulers in that node, which is your scheduler.